# Relation between acrobat and principle of conservation of angular momentum

Tags: angular-momentum, rigid-body-dynamics

How the principle of conservation of angular momentum is used by an acrobat to rotate a few revolution while leaping throung the air?

Answer (score 3):

Angular momentum $L$ can be written as

$L=I\omega$

where $I$ is the moment of inertia and $\omega$ is the angular velocity. In midair, the angular momentum of an acrobat is effectively constant. This allows the acrobat to increase or decrease their angular velocity at will by changing their moment of inertia, i.e., changing the relative distribution of the mass in their bodies with respect to their center of mass. To increase angular velocity, the acrobat can decrease their moment of inertia by bringing more of the mass of their body closer to their center of mass. Alternatively, to decrease angular velocity the acrobat can move more of the mass of their body away from their center of mass. However, decreasing the moment of inertia requires the release of stored energy, which in the case of humans comes in the form of stored chemical energy in the ATP in human cells.

The acrobat may speed up or slow down their rotation, but cannot bring the rotation to a complete stop or reverse the direction of rotation without changing their angular momentum.

Comment: Great answer! Maybe add sent additional information as to why we know angular momentum is conserved, just so the OP can get the complete picture.

Comment: Shouldn't answer homework questions.

Comment: @safesphere I don't think this qualifies as an answer to a homework-like question. Yes, the original post could have mentioned some thoughts, but I believe it's still ok.

Comment: @Chair The question reads like a copy-paste from a textbook, like written by someone who knows the answer and tests others. If you don't see it, you are easy to take advantage of. Water under the bridge.